# Evenly distributed random non-stops

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, random-numbers

I am trying again to recreate some strange images. I am trying to generate hexagons of nonstop with three colors. The distribution of these three should be

```
Color 1 = (N-1)^2
Color 2 = (N-1)*N
Color 3 = N^2
```

where N is the side length of the non stops. The result should look something like this.

[image]

**NOTE:** Here 4 colors is used, I only need 3! Secondly the distribution itself is wrong in the image above.

The idea is then to "sort" the nonstop to make the figure below

[image]

I am able to create the hexagonal non stop pattern (after a lot of work!), see below.

[image]

What I want to improve is this

- How can I control exactly how many of each color type that is present in the hexagon. I still want them to appear randomly in the hexagon.
- Any improvements in apperance to look a bit more like actual candy would be much appreciated.
- Is there an easier approach to generating the hexagon? I had to do a lot of mathematics, and trial and error to get the result right. (Also why is there a small space between my rows?).

Any other approach to obtain the result is much appreciated.

## Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen, tikz}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\definecolor{maincolorMedium}{HTML}{425b9b}

\tikzset{
    nonstop/.style={
      circle,
      minimum size=10mm,
      inner sep=0mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      rotate=0,
    draw
    }
}

\definecolor{nonstopRed}{HTML}{EB4F5C}
\definecolor{nonstopYellow}{HTML}{FFE103}
\definecolor{nonstopBlack}{HTML}{02031B}

\newcommand{\ballcolor}{none}

% Example: Pick color by ID
\newcommand{\incolor}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rng}{int(random(1,3))}
    \ifthenelse{\rng < 2}{ \renewcommand{\ballcolor}{nonstopRed}}{%
    \ifthenelse{\rng < 3}{ \renewcommand{\ballcolor}{nonstopYellow} }{%
                           \renewcommand{\ballcolor}{nonstopBlack}
    }
    }
}

\newcommand{\createNonstop}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\hexagonSize{#1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\J}{2*\hexagonSize-1}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,\J} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\offset}{0.5*Mod(\j,2)}
        \ifthenelse{\j > \hexagonSize}
           {\pgfmathsetmacro{\hexLength}{\hexagonSize + \J - \j}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\jIndent}{0.5*(\J - \j)}}
           {\pgfmathsetmacro{\hexLength}{\hexagonSize + \j-1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\jIndent}{0.5*(\j-1)}}
        \foreach \k in {1,...,\hexLength} {
        \incolor
            \node[nonstop,fill=\ballcolor] at (\k  -\jIndent,\j) {};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\createNonstop{2}

\createNonstop{3}

\createNonstop{4}

\createNonstop{5}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, my previous post did not include the requirement on the number of colors, which I corrected now. This code runs through a loop of `3*N*(N+1)+1` steps (note that my definition of `N` is your `N+1`) and then selects a random number between `1` and `n_tot=3*N*(N+1)+1`, between `1` and `n_tot=3*N*(N+1)` and so on, where in each step one color item gets taken out, hence the three counters `none`, `ntwo` and `nthree`. At each step `none+ntwo+nthree=n_tot` and the counter of each color pile gets reduced. This ensures that there will be `(N+1)^2` smarties of the first color, `N*(N+1)` of the second color and `N^2` of the last color. The lattice is just constructed layer by layer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\newcounter{none}
\newcounter{ntwo}
\newcounter{nthree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/hegrid/.style={code={
  \xdef\LstOne{""}
  \setcounter{none}{\the\numexpr(#1+1)*(#1+1)}
  \setcounter{ntwo}{\the\numexpr#1*(#1+1)}
  \setcounter{nthree}{\the\numexpr#1*#1}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Nm}{int(3*#1*(#1+1)+1)}
  \foreach \YY in {\Nm,\the\numexpr\Nm-1,...,1}
  {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{random(1,\YY)}
  \ifnum\itest>\number\value{none}\relax
   \ifnum\itest>\the\numexpr\YY-\number\value{nthree}\relax
    \addtocounter{nthree}{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCols}[2]}
    \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne,"\mycol"}
   \else    
    \addtocounter{ntwo}{-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCols}[1]}
    \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne,"\mycol"}
   \fi
  \else
   \addtocounter{none}{-1}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCols}[0]}
   \xdef\LstOne{\LstOne,"\mycol"}
  \fi}
  \setcounter{none}{1}
  \path [/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstOne}[1]}]
  node[smartie=\mycol]{};
  \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
  {\foreach \YY [count=\NYY] in {0,...,5}
  {\path (\NYY*60:\XX) -- (\YY*60:\XX) foreach \ZZ in {1,...,\XX} 
  {\pgfextra{\stepcounter{none}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstOne}[\number\value{none}]}}
  node[smartie=\mycol,pos={\ZZ/\XX}]{}};}}}},
  smartie/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=3mm,blur shadow,
  path picture={\shade[ball color=#1] (0.15,-0.15) circle[radius=9mm];}}]
 \edef\LstCols{"red","blue","green!70!black"}
 \path (0,0) pic{hegrid=1} (5,0) pic{hegrid=2}
 (2,-6) pic{hegrid=3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The ordered pattern is much easier to obtain.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/ordered hegrid/.style={code={
  \path [/utils/exec=\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCols}[0]}]
  node[smartie=\mycol]{};
  \foreach \XX in {1,...,#1}
  {\foreach \YY [count=\NYY] in {0,...,5}
  {\path (\NYY*60+60:\XX) -- (\YY*60+60:\XX) foreach \ZZ in {1,...,\XX} 
  {\pgfextra{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myind}{ifthenelse(\NYY<3 || (\NYY==3 && \ZZ == \XX),0,ifthenelse(\NYY<5,1,2))}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycol}{{\LstCols}[\myind]}}
  node[smartie=\mycol,pos={\ZZ/\XX}]{}};}}}},
  smartie/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=3mm,blur shadow,
  path picture={\shade[ball color=#1] (0.15,-0.15) circle[radius=9mm];}}]
 \edef\LstCols{"red","blue","green!70!black"}
 \path (0,0) pic{ordered hegrid=1} (5,0) pic{ordered hegrid=2}
 (2,-6) pic{ordered hegrid=3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note to myself: mini-issue in the new option `parse=true` in foreach.

Comment: Wow! This looks amazing! Any idea how to also produce the sorted output image at the bottom? I tried to change your code, but alas it was outside my abilities.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Oh sorry, I missed that, too. This one is much easier.